# Parallel programming. compute() method, java

Tags: java, data-structures, mergesort

I have this class which extends `RecursiveAction`.
that same class contains constructor which takes array as argument and `compute()` method. 
Inside compute method, it says next:
if `array` length is bigger than 500, split that array in two halves and sort them by `MergeSort.merge()` method. if array length is less than 500, just sort the `array`.

```
private static class SortTask extends RecursiveAction {
   private final int THRESHOLD = 500;
     private int[] list;
      SortTask(int[] list) {
       this.list = list;
         }
        @Override
protected void compute() {
if (list.length < THRESHOLD)
java.util.Arrays.sort(list);
else {
    // Obtain the first half
int[] firstHalf = new int[list.length / 2];
System.arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, list.length / 2);


// Obtain the second half
int secondHalfLength = list.length - list.length / 2;
int[] secondHalf = new int[secondHalfLength];
System.arraycopy(list, list.length / 2,
secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
// Recursively sort the two halves
invokeAll(new SortTask(firstHalf),
new SortTask(secondHalf));
// Merge firstHalf with secondHalf into list
MergeSort.merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, list);
}
}
}
}
```

It says
"recursively sort the two halves" and it does that by:

```
invokeAll(new SortTask(firstHalf), new SortTask(secondHalf));
```

does that mean that every time `new` `SortTask` object is created, `compute()` method is called ?

Comment: If the list is under THRESHOLD no additional SortTask is created. Otherwise at least an additional pair number (2, 4, 6, 8...) of SortTask is created.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. Compute is not a part of `Task` constructor. The simpliest situation is pool `shutdownNow()` -  this call will try to terminate/interrupt all submited tasks.

Every time `new SortTask` created `ForkJoinPool` forks this task:

```
public static void invokeAll(ForkJoinTask<?>... tasks) {
    Throwable ex = null;
    int last = tasks.length - 1;
    for (int i = last; i >= 0; --i) {
        ForkJoinTask<?> t = tasks[i];
        if (t == null) {
            if (ex == null)
                ex = new NullPointerException();
        }
        else if (i != 0)
            t.fork();
    ...
}
```

`compute` method is your task payload - `ForkJoinPool` will do it on it's *schedule*.

From `ForkJoinTask` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html):

> The primary coordination mechanisms are fork(), that arranges
>   asynchronous execution, and join(), that doesn't proceed until the
>   task's result has been computed.

`RecursiveTask` implements abstract method:

```
protected final boolean exec() {
    result = compute();
    return true;
}
```

`ForkJoinWorkerThread` has method:

```
final void More execTask(ForkJoinTask<?> t) {
    currentSteal = t;
    for (;;) {
       if (t != null)
           t.doExec();
    ...
}
```

and at the and `doExec` calls `exec`

```
final void doExec() {
    if (status >= 0) {
        boolean completed;
        try {
            completed = exec();
    ...
}
```

Comment: invokeAll is called in compute(), and compute() is nowhere called explicitly. so once again, I am wondering if compute() is called everytime SortTask object is created, or that is not true

Comment: To start computation you should call `new ForkJoinPool().invoke(new SortTask(data));`

Comment: Compute is not a part of the constructor but it gets called after the instantiation of the RecursiveAction classes. `Note` that you have to implement compute method whenever you extend RecursiveAction. His question though is whether it gets called or not, not whether it is part of it.

Comment: Imagine `ForkJoinPool` with one worker thread. Let us have Task that could be divided to 100. We call `pool = new ForkJoinPool(Task)` and then `pool.shutdownNow()` in this case compute will not be called for all subtasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every time new SortTask object is created, compute() method is called, because the method [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#invokeAll(java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask,%20java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask)) forkes a set of tasks in a ForkJoinPool which implicitly calls compute for each one of them.

> Method invoke() is semantically equivalent to fork(); join() but always attempts to ***begin*** execution in the current thread.

Also from the documentation:

> Normally, a concrete ForkJoinTask subclass (RecursiveAction/RecursiveTask)  declares fields comprising its parameters, established in a constructor, and then defines a ***compute*** method that somehow uses the control methods supplied by this base class.

The method used to sort them here actually is to recursively divide them that when they reach the THRESHOLD they will be sorted sequentially, the merge method is used to merge them after they get sorted. Look at this similar example:

```
class SortTask extends RecursiveAction {
final long[] array; final int lo; final int hi;
SortTask(long[] array, int lo, int hi) {
this.array = array; this.lo = lo; this.hi = hi;
}
protected void compute() {
 if (hi - lo < THRESHOLD)
   sequentiallySort(array, lo, hi);
  else {
   int mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
    coInvoke(new SortTask(array, lo, mid),
            new SortTask(array, mid+1, hi));
   merge(array, lo, hi);
       }
return null;
}
}
```

When [`coInvoke`](http://www.javac.info/jsr166z/jsr166z/forkjoin/RecursiveAction.html#coInvoke(jsr166z.forkjoin.RecursiveAction,%20jsr166z.forkjoin.RecursiveAction)) here Forks both tasks and returns when `isDone` holds for both.

Comment: compute call is async

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin What I wrote was from the documentation!, I still believe in this answer so I am not going to delete it.